# Concatenate Strings to make column alias

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to make a column alias that concatenates strings (one coming from a parameter).

I'm running the same query with different values on the parameter to generate my report to send out, and I want the parameter value included in the column headers/names so that it is clear to the end user (and to myself 30 seconds later) which parameter was used.

I'm trying something like this, but it won't execute

```sql
declare @fy int
set @fy = 2021

select 
    [Section Name],
    [Revenue] as concat(str(@fy),' Earned Revenue'),
    ...
    ...
```

A complete toy example for trying is like this (less stuff, lets just make the param a string

```sql
declare @fy nvarchar(4)
set @fy = '2021'

select 
    'asdf' as concat(@fy,' column')
```

I'm getting

> Incorrect syntax near '@fy'.`

Comment: An alias **must** be a literal, not an expression. If you need an expression then you should be doing that in your application layer.

Comment: The only way to do that is by generating your SQL query at run time (a.k.a. dynamic sql) and then running it with `sp_executesql`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

Comment: Honestly, this smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info); what is the real problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: There are a few, messy ways to do this, dynamic sql as Peter B suggested, alter table via dynamic sql etc but I would try to avoid these. If I wanted to do this I would simply add another column called, for example, 'MeasureName' and use the `CONCAT` expression as the value. This might not be suitable for your scenario ...

Comment: This is usually a really bad idea, because while it might make it easier for user, the actual sql code can easily become impossible to understand. Plus, whoever is reading the values need to be able to handle the dynamic names. Finally, what's wrong with including a column called Year that contains 2021

Comment: thanks, all, this is helpful. this is a report i have to run every two years, each time for, well, two fiscal years. so i just wanted to save the sql query somewhere and pull it up two years from now, change a single param and rerun it. i'm just running directly in SSMS, so the 'applicaiton layer' is me updating it in excel/email. Sounds like that is the correct thing here. I was hoping to get something as close as possible to my end product that i could just copy-paste out of SSMS, which I understand is maybe not what SSMS is for, but figured I'd try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names of database objects such as tables, columns, stored procedures, views, etc, can contain alphanumeric characters and **must begin** with an alphabet or an underscore, not with digit.

We need to use dynamic query to achieve dynamic column alias name.

```
DECLARE @fy INT = 2021; 
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000) = 'SELECT 1234 AS EarnedRevenue'+CAST(@fy AS NVARCHAR(4));
EXEC (@sql)
```

[image]

Comment: this looks like it accomplishes what I asked for, but I'm convinced by the comments that just because one maybe can doesn't mean they should.